# org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a project that functions like an ecommerce website, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I assumed that the error was happening because I have three configure() methods in my SecurityConfig, so I tried making the method names unique, but that did not solve the issue. The following is the error I am getting, and after that is my code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'SecurityConfig' contains overloaded @Bean methods with name 'configure'. Use unique method names for separate bean definitions (with individual conditions etc) or switch '@Configuration.enforceUniqueMethods' to 'false'.
Offending resource: class path resource [com/ecommerce/website/configuration/SecurityConfig.class]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClass.validate(ConfigurationClass.java:233) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.validate(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:398) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.ecommerce.website.EcommerceWebsiteApplication.main(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

Main class

```
package com.ecommerce.website;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.ecommerce.website.controller.AdminController;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository;
import com.ecommerce.website.service.CategoryService;


/**This is the main class. It allows the user to run the project */
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan
public class EcommerceWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Role POJO

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

//Class to represent a role
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id; 
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name; 
    
    //Referencing users
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;
 
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    
    
}
```

User POJO

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    //id for each user 
    //The @GeneratedValue annotation is to configure the way of increment of the specified column (field)
    //GenerationType.AUTO picks an appropriate strategy for the particular database 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id; 
    
    //Field to hold first name 
    //@NotEmpty means that the field cannot be null or empty
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName; 
    
    //Field to hold email 
    //@Column maps to email column in table; it is not nullable and has to be unique 
    //@NotEmpty means that the field cannot be null or empty
    //@Email shows message if email is invalid 
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    @Email(message = "{errors.invalid_email}")
    private String email; 
    
    //Field to hold password 
    private String password;
    
    //Creating list to reference and hold roles (admin and user)
    //This is @ManyToMany because one user can have many roles and one role can have many users 
    //Cascade applies the same operation to related entities
        //????CascadeType.MERGE says if entity is merged, related entity is also merged
    //Eager FetchType will receive all data 
    //@JoinTable is used to reference join table, which provides mapping between two tables
        //It has foreign keys for each table to define the mapping relationship 
        //In this case, "user_role" is the name of the join table
        //"USER_ID" and "ROLE_ID" refer to those columns in the join table
        //Application looks at above columns and uses info to find relationship between users and roles 
        //We are defining relationship in User class, so Role is on the inverse/other side 
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn (name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;
    
    
    
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    public User(User user) {
        super();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    } 
    
}
```

RoleRepository

```
package com.ecommerce.website.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>{

}
```

```
package com.ecommerce.website.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    //Method to find user by email (optional because user may not be found)
    Optional<User> findUserByEmail(String email); 
}
```

LoginController

```
package com.ecommerce.website.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.ecommerce.website.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    //Injecting dependencies 
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    //Mappings to return login and register pages 
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerGet() {
        return "register";
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailService

```
package com.ecommerce.website.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.CustomUserDetail;
import com.ecommerce.website.model.User;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    //Injecting dependency 
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    //Method to find a user by their email 
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        return user.map(CustomUserDetail::new).get();
    }

}
```

CustomUserDetail

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

/**This class connects the User model with UserDetails, which provides core user information. 
 * This class extends User so that it can use methods from that class like .getUsername() and .getPassword() */
public class CustomUserDetail extends User implements UserDetails {
    
    //Creating constructor to get username and password of user 
    public CustomUserDetail(User user) {
        
        //Calling super() so that parent can pass in the user object
        super(user);
    }

    //This method returns the authorities (roles) that a user has 
    //@return authorityList because a user can have multiple roles
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
        //List to hold users authorities (roles)
            //Holds type GrantedAuthority, which represents an authority granted to an Authentication object
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //Calling super to get each roles that a user has 
        //Putting those roles into the list 
        //Converting roles to SimpleGrantedAuthority so that they can be added to list
        super.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        
        });
        
        return authorityList; 
        
    }

    //Method to get username and password
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getEmail();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    //More methods about user 
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig

```
package com.ecommerce.website.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.ecommerce.website.service.CustomUserDetailService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    //Injecting dependencies 
    @Autowired
    GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler googleOAuth2SuccessHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;
    
    //Method to allow and restrict access for certain users 
    @Bean
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/", "/shop/**", "/register", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(googleOAuth2SuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
    
    //Strong hashing function to encoder 
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder () {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    //Method for authentication 
    @Bean
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
    }
    
    //Method that restricts the website from accessing certain folders 
    @Bean
    protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/images/**", "/productImages/**", "/css/**", "/js/**");   
    }
    
}
```

GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler

```
package com.ecommerce.website.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Role;
import com.ecommerce.website.model.User;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.UserRepository;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    //Injecting dependencies 
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    //RedirectStrategy variable to redirect HTTP requests if needed 
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = (RedirectStrategy) new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        //Token to represent OAuth2AuthenticationToken
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication; 
        
        //Getting email 
        String email = token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("email").toString(); 
        
        //If loop to find user by email 
        if(userRepository.findUserByEmail(email).isPresent()) {
            
        }
        //Else block for if user is not found 
        else {
            //Creating user, setting its info, and saving it 
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("given_name").toString());
            user.setLastName(token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("family_name").toString());
            user.setEmail(email);
            List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.add(roleRepository.findById(2).get());
            user.setRoles(roles);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
        
        //Redirecting HTTP request 
        ((DefaultRedirectStrategy) redirectStrategy).sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, "/"); 
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You clearly have 3 methods with the same name (and returning `void` from an `@Bean` method doesn't make sense). Looks like you took an old configuration class and tried to shoehorn that into the new Spring Security configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the feedback! I am following an older tutorial, yes. In your opinion, where is the best place I can learn about the new configuration classes for authentication?

Comment: The Spring Security documentation and blog posts around the 5.7 and 6.0 releases of Spring Security.

Answer (score 2):

In your `SecurityConfig.java`, I believe there are 2 problems:

1. A bean with the name `configure` will almost certainly conflict with something. It should have a different name like `securityOAuth2filter`.
2. You should return `http.build()` which is a `SecurityFilterChain` and not `void`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Am I supposed to change all of the configure() methods to securityOAuth2filter()? Also, am I supposed to make all methods return http.build()?

Comment: @Sohaib to avoid the error in your question: use unique names for your beans, the name `configure` is used for something else inside spring. regarding OAuth: you should return `http.build()`.